# "Screen size" app in Angular

Tags: css, angular, flexbox

I'm attempting to create a "screen size" app in Angular. The app total height (including header, toolbars, "content area" with router-outlets etc') should be the screen size (100vh). i.e no "html body" scrolling.

The children components in content area should expand to the bottom of the screen. in other words, fill the height of thier container (the content area).

What is the best approach to accomplish that?

the closest i've got was to add the following to styles.css file:

```
app-root {
    display: block;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

but setting some  inside a component to {height : 100%} does not seems to make it expand to the bottom of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

to achieve this you have the parent div to be height 100%

```
html, body {height: 100%;}
```

has to be added,

for your reference http://me.expanse.me/ , is a site build as like your requirement(html and css site), hope this will help you.